# Aws Cognito Hosted UI. Return error message from Triggers

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I'm using hosted UI for user signup and login. I've a pre-signup trigger which deny user based on some criteria. How can I send back the error message to the caller or Callback URL?

Btw, I've tried passing the error back as stated [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-authentication.html#aws-lambda-triggers-pre-authentication-example), but it doesn't work. I'm guessing it's because I'm using hosted UI.

Thanks,
Simon

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue discussed here [link](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-android/issues/1907)

I would like to say there is no solution for this as of now. I have tried everything but due to hosted UI it is not returning that error message. In my case I'm getting error:

```
AuthException{message=Sign-in with web UI failed, 
cause=com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognitoauth.exceptions.AuthServiceException: 
invalid_request, recoverySuggestion=See attached exception for more details}.
```

It is telling `invalid_request` instead of lambda error message.